# CardView onTouch onClick

Tags: android, android-studio

i am trying to animate a CardView if it getting clicked, but the onTouch method don't works on it. The view don't notice the touch, but in android studio there is this information showing:

> Custom view `MaterialCardView` has setOnTouchListener called on it but does not override performClick less... (Strg+F1) 
>   If a View that overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also implement performClick and call it when clicks are detected, the View may not handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the click actions should ideally be placed in View#performClick as some accessibility services invoke performClick when a click action should occur.  Issue id: ClickableViewAccessibility

I have added this:
So i have added this thing:

> ```
> @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
> ```

But anyways it isn't working, but maybe this could be the mistake.

Here is my CardViewAdapter.class

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.card.MaterialCardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class CardViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewAdapter.CardViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems;
    private Context context;
    private Resources resources;


    public CardViewAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> listItems, Context context, Resources resources) {
        this.listItems = listItems;
        this.context = context;
        this.resources = resources;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_illness_card, parent, false);
        return new CardViewHolder(layoutView);
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardViewHolder cardViewHolder, final int position) {
        final HashMap<String, String> listItem = listItems.get(position);


        int resID = resources.getIdentifier(listItem.get("image_1"), "drawable", context.getPackageName());

        cardViewHolder.illnessTitle.setText(listItem.get("title_1"));
        cardViewHolder.illnessSubtitle.setText(listItem.get("freetime_1"));
        cardViewHolder.illnessEngagement.setText("");
        cardViewHolder.illnesImage.setBackgroundResource(resID);

        cardViewHolder.cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setScaleX(0.95f);
                    v.setScaleY(0.95f);

                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    v.animate().cancel();
                    v.animate().scaleX(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
                    v.animate().scaleY(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });



        cardViewHolder.linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ViewPagerPreviewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView illnesImage;
        TextView illnessTitle;
        TextView illnessSubtitle;
        LinearLayout linearLayout;
        TextView illnessEngagement;
        MaterialCardView cardView;


        public CardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.materialCard);
            illnesImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_image);
            illnessTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_title);
            illnessSubtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_description);
            linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            illnessEngagement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_engagement);


        }

    }
}
```

Would be cool if some could help me! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you implement 'OnTouchListener' on a view as the document says, should invoke 'performClick()' method manually; OK? so you change your code to this:

```
cardViewHolder.cardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    v.setScaleX(0.95f);
                    v.setScaleY(0.95f);

                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    v.animate().cancel();
                    v.animate().scaleX(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
                    v.animate().scaleY(1f).setDuration(1000).start();

                    // Here for example
                    performClick();
                }

                return false;
            }
        });
```

It is in your hand to when click should be invoked! in here I said that invoke click when action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: `Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

this code will run multiple time's and make the toast visible multiple number's of time better to keep it inside UP or DOWN event and `return true` from the onTouch then it might work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CardViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnTouchListener {

    ImageView illnesImage;
    TextView illnessTitle;
    TextView illnessSubtitle;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    TextView illnessEngagement;
    MaterialCardView cardView;


    public CardViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.materialCard);
        illnesImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_image);
        illnessTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_title);
        illnessSubtitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_description);
        linearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        illnessEngagement = itemView.findViewById(R.id.illness_engagement);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // calling toast should be specific not for all the event's
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int action = event.getAction();
            if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  // adding toast here means user has pressed the card.
                v.setScaleX(0.95f);
                v.setScaleY(0.95f);

            } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                v.animate().cancel();
                v.animate().scaleX(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
                v.animate().scaleY(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
            }

            return true;  //this should be true to get further event's
        }
}
```

I have set the `onTouchListener inside ViewHolder` to keep the code clean.You are returning `false` from `onTouch()` which is *wrong*.Once you return *false* from *onTouch()* (i.e on `ACTION_DOWN`) then you won't be getting any further event's so *return true* from `onTouch()` to keep accepting the event's.

*NOTE: Below warning can be ignored and no need of adding any annotation's.*

> Custom view MaterialCardView has setOnTouchListener called on it but
>   does not override performClick less... (Strg+F1) If a View that
>   overrides onTouchEvent or uses an OnTouchListener does not also
>   implement performClick and call it when clicks are detected, the View
>   may not handle accessibility actions properly. Logic handling the
>   click actions should ideally be placed in View#performClick as some
>   accessibility services invoke performClick when a click action should
>   occur. Issue id: ClickableViewAccessibility